# What kind of redirection Type is dyndns using?

Tags: redirect, vpn, dyndns, l2tp

So i'm curious what kind of redirection dyndns.org ist using.
We used to have an Account there but we cancelled it, we build a Inhouse IP collection solution.

BUT:

Some host urls XY.dyndns.org where used for VPN (unifi l2tp) connections and i can't figure out how i have to setupt the php or .htaccess for redirecting like dyndns.org urls. dyndns was host with ip setting

what i have:

- danymic IP
- some Domain vpn.domain.com which gets my external IP from Modem at home (domainserver is in some Datacenter)
- solution must be done with JS, PHP or .htaccess

what i want is:

vpn.domain.com is used as VPN Target Server Domain
This Domain should redirect to my external IP from Home which is the real VPN Access Point. When i use the IP directly the VPN tunnel is created properly.

i already tried with php header location and .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://10.125.111.111/$1 [R=301,L]
```

so i'm out of knowledge, please bring me in right direction.

what i

Tanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could research, I would need some root server with the ability to change the IP Routing Tables. My 0815 Webserver isn't the right the choice for this.